# Activity starts but I need to minimize to see it

Tags: java, android

I have a splash screen that is an activity, after 2 seconds it will launch the login activity but the screen remains the same. If I change to home screen and go back to app, the screen updates to the login activity. This is happening recently, before I didn't see this issue. Also I haven't touched anything from the splash screen.

I'm using a Handler with postDelayed.

handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);

Comment: Can you add you splash screen code ?

Answer (score 1):

you are going to splash the screen to the next activity when you write the finish() because you don't want to again open this activity when the user press back press.

The same thing is the log-in screen when the user enters your login details in this time you enter the boolean value in the Sharepreference variable and also finish() login activity.

The next time the user opens the app splash screen will be visible when the splash screen visible you decide the activity through share preference variable data where you are going.